# Does sklearn clustering output differs due to machine?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn AffinityPropagation clustering algorithm . The output  of the clustering algorithm on  my 4 core machine is different than what is getting generated on a typical server machine. Can someone suggest any method so that I can get similar output on both the systems.

I am using similar feature vector on both the machine.

Output on my machine is  cluster0:[1,2,3],cluster1:[4,5,6] but on server its cluster0:[1,2] cluster1:[3,4],cluster2:[5]

```py
from keras.applications.xception import Xception
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.xception import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import cv2
import glob
base_model = Xception(weights = model_path)
base_model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=base_model.get_layer('avg_pool').output)
files = glob.glob("*.jpg")
image_vector = []
for f in files:
   image = cv2.imread(f)
   temp_vector = base_model.predict(image)
   image_vector.append(temp_vector)

import numpy as np
image_vector = np.asarray(image_vector)
clustering = AffinityPropagation()
clustering.fit(image_vector)
```

Packages :- 
scikit-learn 0.20.3
sklearn 0.0
tensorflow 1.12.0
keras 2.2.4
opencv-python

Machine 1 :- 4 core 8GB RAM
Machine 2 :- 7 Core 16GB RAM

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is impossible for anyone to help you with the practically zero-information you have actually provided; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @desertnaut hello . Thanks for the response .Can you please tell me what more information will help you understand the question better. Thanks

Comment: @etherjain versions of your software packages, your hardware, all the data that can help us with reproducing this problem

Comment: @Vladimir Thank for suggesting the details required.

Answer (score 0):

Results on different machines can be different when running algorithms that are not deterministic.

I suggest that you fix the random seed of numpy and the random seed of Python if you want to be able to reproduce results across machines for such algorithms.

Python random seed can be fixed by using: `random.seed(42)` (or any other integer)

Numpy random seed can be fixed with: `np.random.seed(12345)` (or any other integer)

sklearn and Keras use numpy random number generator so the second option by itself could solve your issue.

This answer assumes that all libraries versions are the same on both systems.

Comment: setting the np.random.seed() is not helping. I am sure that library version are same as I am using conda environment in both the system.

Comment: @etherjain Are you using a GPU to train your model? Some randomness could come from this. Keras uses numpy random number generator so does sklearn, so fixing the seed should make the results reproducible.

Comment: I am not training on GPU. Its all CPU based.There is no training involved except the clustering.fit() function.

Comment: on closer look I found that both the Affinity Matrix that is getting generated are different. Not sure why that might be happening.